# Logic to check if the String is a valid number or not

Tags: java

I am uisng the folowing logic to check if a String recievied is a valid number or not

```
package com;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "122";
        boolean b = isNumb(str);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static boolean isNumb(String str) {
        String s = str;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

I am going to use this in a highly multithreaded environment where there can be 800 - 900 concurrent users at a time , please let me know , if this code has got any loop holes or not ??

Please share your views

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java

Comment: Btw, your code won't work with floating point numbers, not even talking about hex and stuff.

Comment: Your approach is completely okay. Another alternative is to use `str.toCharArray()` and directly check on the resulting `char[]` to not check bounds in the `charAt()` method. But I don't think you'll notice the performance improvement for small strings (especially vs. the garbage char[] generated that needs to be collected).

Comment: Your code will break on negative numbers :)

Comment: @anubhava Overkill? :p

Comment: `String s = str` is of no use in your code.

Comment: By the way you should store s.length in a variable and use that variable in the for loop. This way the length of the string will be calculated only once. (Will be noticeable for longer strings)

Answer (score 5):

I would use regex:

```
public static boolean isNumb(String str) {
    return str.matches("\\d+");
}
```

To return true for negative numbers too, add an optional leading dash:

```
return str.matches("-?\\d+");
```

Comment: @giorashc This is an alternative to the code OP has written, which doesn't check negative numbers. But you do have a point, of course.

Comment: regex will be slower than checking each character.

Comment: @giorashc I've added negative number support

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to check if a string is a number, such as using a regular expression.

```
s.matches("^-?\\d+(\\.\\d)?$")
```

will easily pick up whether the string is number, where s is your string.

Comment: This allows for only one decimal place. And in the context of `matches`, you don't need `^` and `$` anchors.

Answer (score 2):

For validating if given string is a valid number (not just Integer):

```
boolean b = str.matches("^[+-]?(?=.)\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$");
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply do the following to check if a String is a number:

```
try {
    final Integer i = Integer.parseInt("Your String");
} catch(final NumberFormatException nfe) {
    //String is no number
}
```

Comment: This has a performance issue when the check fails. It is an example of the "using exceptions for flow control" anti-pattern. Still, it *is* a reliable approach.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If it is expected that most inputs will be numbers, this is a good compromise (performance is as good as loop on char when no exception is thrown).

Comment: @assylias Personally, I rarely ever bother using anything else, mainly due to the reliability aspect. There is always something that may be wrong with my regex, or any other complex logic I may have. In fact, I'm a bit mad at the JDK for not providing a non-throwing method itself.